# TYPO3 8.7.22 PAGE UID CSS

Tags: css, typo3, styling, typo3-8.x

I was wondering if its possible to use the PAGE UID in CSS to style each site from the website different.

Best regards

Comment: If Page UID is being output in the DOM, then of course yes!

Comment: @m4n0 I didn't see the Page UID in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to include the Page UID to the body.

```
page.bodyTag >
page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
page.bodyTagCObject {
    field = uid
    wrap = <body class="uid-|">
}
```